# pyautogui перестает работать корректор

Tags: python, pyautogui

Этот код делает все что должен, но он просто перестал работать в конкретном документе. 'shift','ctrl','f' не нажимает и вместо текста вводит 3 пробела. При том при создании нового кода все работает корректно. При этом попробовал еще через `keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + f' )`, и это тоже не работает. Почему может так происходить?

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time

Head = None
while Head == None:
    Head = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('Ways/1CHead.png')
    pg.hotkey('shift','ctrl','f')
pg.typewrite('Gjcnegktybt yf hfcxtnysq cxtn')
time.sleep(0.5)
pg.typewrite(['Enter'])
```

Comment: При этом проверил еще и CTRL + C / V, Так же не работают

Comment: В общем суть проблемы в том что почему то он не реагирует на нажатия букв, при чем не важно какой системный язык стоит и на каком языке я хочу вводить.

Comment: Я разобрался. Проблема была в том что запуск скрипта должен осуществляться с системным языком Анг.